# jQuery AJAX post not receiving data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project, and I'm not getting any data back from an AJAX post. I have a form set up to run a search with all kinds of parameters. The PHP is most definitely getting the correct data -- I have error logs that confirm that the PHP itself is working -- but nothing is coming through on the jQuery side. I've tried echoing the array, json_encoding the array, simply returning the array, etc., but nothing comes through. "success" and "error" functions do not execute at all. What I'm posting are the LATEST versions of the files; I've tried variations...but first, the method that's being called in the model:

```
    function search_games($data) {
    $dbSelect = "SELECT `gameTitle`";
    $include_count = 0;
    // Count items in arrays - console, stuff to include, stuff to exclude
    foreach ($data['include'] as $include => $val) {
        if ($val === 'true') {
            $include_count++;
            $dbSelect .= ',`'.$include.'`';
        }
    }

    $dbSelect .= " FROM tbUserGames ";
    $console_count = count($data['console']);


    // Include these consoles
    switch ($console_count) {
        case 1:
            $dbWhere = "WHERE ((gamePlatform=".$data['console'][0]." ";
            break;
        case 2:
            $dbWhere = "WHERE ((gamePlatform=".$data['console'][0];
            $dbWhere .= " OR gamePlatform=".$data['console'][1]." ";
            break;
        case 3:
            $dbWhere = "WHERE ((gamePlatform=".$data['console'][0];
            $dbWhere .= " OR gamePlatform=".$data['console'][1];
            $dbWhere .= " OR gamePlatform=".$data['console'][2]." ";
            break;
    }
    $dbWhere .= ")";

    // Include games that have manual, box, and/or notes:
    if ($data['manual'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND gameManual=1";
    }

    if ($data['box'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND gameBox=1";
    }

    if ($data['notes'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND notes IS NOT NULL";
    }

    // Exclude games that have manual, box, and/or notes
    if ($data['emanual'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND NOT gameManual=1";
    }

    if ($data['ebox'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND NOT gameBox=1";
    }

    if ($data['enotes'] == 'true') {
        $dbWhere .= " AND notes IS NULL";
    }

    // game titles start with, contain, or end with...
    switch($data['search_terms']) {
        case 'start_with':
            $dbLike = " AND gameTitle LIKE '".$data['search_key']."%'";
            break;
        case 'contain':
            $dbLike = " AND gameTitle LIKE '%".$data['search_key']."%'";
            break;
        case 'end_with':
            $dbLike = " AND gameTitle LIKE '%".$data['search_key']."'";
            break;
    }

    // AA Rarity rating: exactly, at least, at most, greater than, less than, all but
    $dbWhere .= " AND ((atariagecom_rarity ";
    switch($data['rarity_fuzz_drop']) {
        // NOTE: THESE CASES NEED FIXING TO WORK WITH HOMEBREWS, PROTOS, REPROS, AND UNKNOWNS
        case 'at_least':
            $dbWhere .= "BETWEEN ".$data['rarity_options']." AND 10)";
            break;
        case 'greater_than':
            $dbWhere .= "BETWEEN ".((int)$data['rarity_options']+1)." and 10)";
            break;
        case 'exactly':
            $dbWhere .= "= ".$data['rarity_options'].")";
            break;
        case 'less_than':
            $dbWhere .= "< ".$data['rarity_options'].")";
            break;
        case 'at_most':
            $dbWhere .= "<= ".$data['rarity_options'].")";
            break;
        case 'all_but':
            $dbWhere .= "!= ".$data['rarity_options']." AND atariagecom_rarity < 11)";
    }

    /*
     *  Binary format for non-numeric rarity:
     *      homebrew: 1         atariage_com rarity: 11
     *      repro:    2         atariage_com rarity: 12
     *      proto:    4         atariage_com rarity: 13
     *      unknown:  8         atariage_com rarity: 14
     */

    $rar_bin = 0;

    // Include homebrews..
    if ($data['aah'] == 'true') {
        $rar_bin += 1;
    }

    // Include repros...
    if ($data['aar'] == 'true') {
        $rar_bin += 2;
    }

    // Include protos...
    if ($data['aap'] == 'true') {
        $rar_bin += 4;
    }

    // Include games of undetermined rarity...
    if ($data['aau'] == 'true') {
        $rar_bin += 8;
    }
    if ($rar_bin > 0) {
        $dbWhere .= " OR ";
        // account for rarity of 11
        if ($rar_bin % 2 === 1) {
            $dbWhere .= "(atariagecom_rarity=11)";
            if ($rar_bin > 1) { 
                $dbWhere .= " OR " ;
            }
        }
        // account for rarity of 12
        if ($rar_bin == 2 || $rar_bin == 3) {
            $dbWhere .= "(atariagecom_rarity=12)";
        }

        // rarity 13 only
        if ($rar_bin == 4) {
            $dbWhere .= "(atariagecom_rarity=13)";
        }

        // account for rarity of both 12 and 13
        if ($rar_bin==5 || $rar_bin==6 || $rar_bin==7 || $rar_bin==12 || $rar_bin==13 || $rar_bin==14 || $rar_bin==15) {
            $dbWhere .= "(atariagecom_rarity=12) OR (atariagecom_rarity=13)";
        }

        if ($rar_bin > 8) {
            $dbWhere .= " OR ";
        }
        // rarity 14
        if ($rar_bin >= 8) {
            $dbWhere .= "(atariagecom_rarity=14)";
        }
        $dbWhere .=")";
    }
    $dbLike .= ")";
    $dbOrderBy = " ORDER BY gameTitle";
    $sql = $dbSelect.$dbWhere.$dbLike.$dbOrderBy;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The model is definitely pulling the correct data, so that works.

Here's the method being executed in the controller -- and this works as well:

```
    function do_search() {
    $this->load->model('listgames_model');
    if ($_POST['a2600'] === 'true') {
        $search_games['console'][] = '2';
    }
    if ($_POST['a5200'] === 'true') {
        $search_games['console'][] = '5';
    }
    if ($_POST['a7800'] === 'true') {
        $search_games['console'][] = '7';
    }
    $search_games['manual'] = $_POST['manual'];
    $search_games['box'] = $_POST['box'];
    $search_games['notes'] = $_POST['notes'];
    $search_games['emanual'] = $_POST['manual'];
    $search_games['ebox'] = $_POST['box'];
    $search_games['enotes'] = $_POST['notes'];
    $search_games['include']['smanual'] = $_POST['manual'];
    $search_games['include']['sbox'] = $_POST['box'];
    $search_games['include']['snotes'] = $_POST['notes'];
    $search_games['search_terms'] = $_POST['search_terms'];
    $search_games['search_key'] = $_POST['search_key'];
    $search_games['rarity_fuzz_drop'] = $_POST['rarity_fuzz_drop'];
    $search_games['rarity_options'] = $_POST['rarity_options'];
    $search_games['aah'] = $_POST['aah'];
    $search_games['aar'] = $_POST['aar'];
    $search_games['aap'] = $_POST['aap'];
    $search_games['aau'] = $_POST['aau'];
    $search_games['include']['gamePlatform'] = $_POST['splatform'];
    $search_games['include']['atariagecom_rarity'] = $_POST['rarity'];
    $search_games['include']['cartColor'] = $_POST['cart_color'];
    $search_games['include']['labelCase'] = $_POST['label_case'];
    $search_games['include']['labelStyle'] = $_POST['label_style'];
    $search_games['include']['overlay'] = $_POST['overlay'];
    $search_result = $this->listgames_model->search_games($search_games);
    if (is_array($search_result)) {
        error_log("IT'S AN ARRAY");
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_userdata('game_data',$search_result); 
        error_log(print_r($search_result,1));
        error_log("echoing");
        echo json_encode($search_result);
    } else {
        return array('success' => false);
    }
}
```

Here's the AJAX call:

```
function validate_list_form() {
var errors = new Array();
var form_data = new Array();
if (($('#a2600').prop('checked') !== true) && ($('#a5200').prop('checked') !== true) && ($('#a7800').prop('checked') !== true)) {
    alert("You need to choose at least one console.");
    return false;
} else {
    $.ajax({type: 'post',
        url: 'listgames/do_search',
        data: {
        'a2600': $('#a2600').prop('checked'),
        'a5200': $('#a5200').prop('checked'),
        'a7800': $('#a7800').prop('checked'),
        'manual': $('#manual').prop('checked'),
        'box': $('#box').prop('checked'),
        'notes': $('#notes').prop('checked'),
        'emanual': $('#emanual').prop('checked'),
        'ebox': $('#ebox').prop('checked'),
        'enotes': $('#enotes').prop('checked'),
        'search_terms': $('#search_terms').val(),
        'search_key' : $('#search_key').val(),
        'rarity_fuzz_drop' : $('#rarity_fuzz_drop').val(),
        'rarity_options' : $('#rarity_options').val(),
        'aah': $('#aah').prop('checked'),
        'aar': $('#aar').prop('checked'),
        'aap': $('#aap').prop('checked'),
        'aau': $('#aau').prop('checked'),
        'splatform': $('#splatform').prop('checked'),
        'smanual': $('#smanual').prop('checked'),
        'sbox': $('#sbox').prop('checked'),
        'snotes': $('#snotes').prop('checked'),
        'rarity': $('#rarity').prop('checked'),
        'cart_color': $('#cart_color').prop('checked'),
        'label_style': $('#label_style').prop('checked'),
        'label_case': $('#label_case').prop('checked'),
        'overlay': $('#overlay').prop('checked')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
        console.log("Here's the result:");
        console.dir(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.log("ERROR:");
            console.dir(result);
        },
        always: function(result) {
            console.log("THIS WILL RUN NO MATTER WHAT");
            console.dir(result);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Firebug always tells me "THIS WILL RUN NO MATTER WHAT," but I get nothing else. Again, THE PHP GIVES ME EXACTLY WHAT I WANT. It just doesn't return the data to jQuery.

What am I not doing right???

Comment: on your browser developer tools on the network tab, did you see it fired a post on the url you provided?

Comment: when you click it and check the response , what does it show? a 404,500 or the json data?

Comment: None of the above. It shows the post data and no responses.

Comment: maybe it is not going to the url it is intended to, is your script located on the php file? try adding `site_url` to the url, to be sure, this wont fix it but we will be sure it really goes to the right url

Comment: Again, the script IS executing. I have error logs that confirm that the PHP script is executing. The error logs are also showing the data that SHOULD be coming back. And I actually did have the site_url variable in there as well at one point and got the exact same result.

Comment: try adding header content-type to `json`

Comment: Okay, just added "header('Content-type:application/json');" to the controller; no difference.

Comment: try to create a new method under listgames like test `listgames/test` and use that with nothing inside but a var_dump of `$_POST` if you still cant see a result on the network debuggin tool tab on your browser, their might be other conflicts on your script, that we are not aware of.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. I did exactly that and it worked exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you need to echo the json instead of return php array.

```
} else {
    return array('success' => false);
}
```

should be

```
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
}
```

Also you are sending with the name of `'sbox': $('#sbox').prop('checked'),` and receiving with the wrong name like `$_POST['box']`

Check this line

```
$search_games['include']['sbox'] = $_POST['box'];
```

Some other line also having same error.

Comment: Hmmm....after changing the "return" to "echo json_encode" the PHP is showing success but the "error" function in the AJAX call is executing, but not "always". Odd, but at least I'm getting some sort of result. :)  Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You have to write error instead of success. Success is the upper part.

Comment: Oh, I should also add...when I look at the post data in Firebug, it shows post data but no response data.

Comment: BTW, Rajiv -- can you clarify wat you mean by "you have to write error instead of success"??? Do you mean for success I should have "'error' => false"?? Tried that and got nothing different.

Comment: And I just realized that "error" is deprecated. Changed "error" to "fail" in the AJAX call and once again I'm getting no results. :(

Comment: But success or error, whatever you get from php response will go only success part in ajax. You need to find weather is that success of failure from the json response.

Comment: If it's not sending any data back, then how am I supposed to be able to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...and it literally took about a month from the time I had the problem. There's nothing wrong with my jQuery, my data, or my PHP. It's...the way I used CodeIgniter.

I used CodeIgniter's form helper to use a submit button -- and that's where the problem was. Using a submit button makes CodeIgniter actually perform its standard form submission function, which causes a reload or a redirect. As a result of that redirect, the AJAX call is cancelled before it can finished, ergo giving me no results. I changed the submit button to a regular button, and *boom!* got the results I need!